# WPF MVVM TextBlock binding to string in a class DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

In my application I have a list of members in a `DataGrid`, and when a member is selected a member profile is populated with their details. The member profile consists of 10+ `TextBlocks` with each text value bound to an individual `DependencyProperty (DP)` of type `string`.

The generated member list is a `List<MEMBERINFO>`, and the `SelectedMember DP` is MEMBERINFO type.

```
public partial class MEMBERINFO
{
    public GD_MEMBERDETAILS MEMBERDETAILS { get; set; }
    public List<GD_ADDRESSDETAILS> ADDRESSDETAILS { get; set; }
    public List<GD_VESSELDETAILS> BOATDETAILS { get; set; }
    public GD_MEMBERSHIPS MEMBERSHIP { get; set; }
    public List<string> FAMILYMEMBERS { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, when a member is selected in the `DataGrid`, `SelectedMember` values are assigned to individual `DependencyProperties` for display in the member profile e.g.

```
MemberName = SelectedMember.MEMBERINFO.MEMBER_NAME;
```

While this works, I feel like there should be a neater way to do this, seeing as I already have all the info I need in `SelectedMember`. So rather than having 10+ string `DependencyProperties` and assigning their values from `SelectedMember`, is there a way to have all the TextBlocks inside a container with an ItemsSource bound to `SelectedMember` and assign bind the text to the properties within `SelectedMember`? So in the same way that you do with a DataGrid? I know that ListView and ListBox also have ItemsSource but my member profile is not a list, I just want a simple container that doesn't have any inherent functionality in the way that DataGrids and ListViews/Box do.

*Note: In another application with a similar problem I managed to manipulate a DataGrid to remove all it's inherent DataGrid functionality and display multiple textblocks in a single cell so that I could use its ItemsSource. But this was quite a pain to do, so again I feel like there should be an easier way!*

Comment: Sounds like you should be displaying your selected member using a datatemplate. You should not be using dependency properties in a viewmodel, however.

Comment: DP in a VM isn't that big of a violation of MVVM.  It isn't really necessary, as INPC properties are superior (they're thread safe, in that you can update them from a non-ui thread and have changes marshalled automatically).  You should grab a copy of the framework guidelines, tho...

Comment: I've only been programming for little over 2 months so I'm on a steep learning curve at the moment! If they're not supposed to be in the ViewModel then where should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just bind the `TextBlock`'s directly to the source properties?:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMember.MEMBERINFO.MEMBER_NAME, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I tried this before, but as soon as I moved my content inside the ItemsControl it's no longer visible?

Comment: What is the ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl set to?

Comment: It's set to my SelectedMember dependency property

Comment: This is wrong. It should be set to a list of objects. Please post *all* relevant parts of your code if you want anyone to be able to help you.